# Attempting login with Scrapy-Splash

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Since i am not able to login to https://www.duif.nl/login, i tried many different methods like selenium, which i successfully logged in, but didnt manage to start crawling.

Now i tried my luck with scrapy-splash, but i cant login :(

If i render the loginpage with splash, i see following picture:

[image: loginpage]

Well, there should be a loginform, like username and password, but scrapy cant see it?

Im sitting here like a week in front of that loginform and losing my will to live..

My last question didnt even get one answer, now i try it again.

here is the html code of the login-form:

[image: html]

When i login manual, i get redirected to "/login?returnUrl=", where i only have these form_data:

[image: form_data]

**My Code**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import ScrapysplashItem
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
import csv

class DuifSplash(CrawlSpider):
    name = "duifsplash"
    allowed_domains = ['duif.nl']
    login_page = 'https://www.duif.nl/login'
    with open('duifonlylinks.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        start_urls = [items['Link'] for items in reader]
        
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
        url=self.login_page,
        callback=self.parse,
        dont_filter=True
        )
        
    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'username' : 'not real',
                'password' : 'login data',
            },  callback=self.after_login)
        
    def after_login(self, response):
        accview = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-accountbox clearfix js-match-height"]/h3')
        if accview:
            print('success')
        else:
            print(':(') 

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)            

    def parse_page(self, response):
        productpage = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-details col-md-12"]')
        
        if not productpage:
            print('No productlink', response.url)
            
        for a in productpage:
            
            items = ScrapysplashItem()
            items['SKU'] = response.xpath('//p[@class="desc"]/text()').get()
            items['Title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="product-title"]/text()').get()
            items['Link'] = response.url
            items['Images'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="inner"]/img/@src').getall()
            items['Stock'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="desc"]/ul/li/em/text()').getall()
            items['Desc'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="item"]/p/text()').getall()
            items['Title_small'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/p/text()').get()
            items['Price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/span/text()').get()
            yield items
```

In my "prework", i crawled every internal link and saved it to a .csv-File, where i analyse which of the links are product links and which are not.
Now i wonder, if i open a link of my csv, it opens an authenticated session or not?
I cant find no cookies, this is also strange to me

**UPDATE**

I managed to login successfully :-) now i only need to know where the cookies are stored

**Lua Script**

```
LUA_SCRIPT = """
function main(splash, args)
    splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies),
    splash:go("https://www.duif.nl/login"),
    splash:wait(0.5),
    local title = splash.evaljs("document.title"),
    return {
        title=title,
        cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
        },
end
"""
```

Comment: To get the cookies, you need to add `cookies = splash:get_cookies()` to the return in your lua-script. In the parse following your SplashRequest, you can find them back in `response.data['cookies']`. You should also activate the SplashCookieMiddleware in the DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES in your settings.py: `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723} `

Comment: @WimHermans, thanks for your answer! i edited my question, where you can see now my lua script. Can you pls have a look at it? its my first time doing lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I don't think using Splash here is the way to go, as even with a normal Request the form is there: `response.xpath('//form[@id="login-form"]')`
- There are multiple forms available on the page, so you have to specify which form you want to base yourself on to make a FormRequest.from_response. Best specify the clickdata as well (so it goes to  'Login', not to 'forgot password'). In summary it would look something like this:

```
req = FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='login-form',
            formdata={
                'username' : 'not real',
                'password' : 'login data'},
            clickdata={'type': 'submit'}
            )
```

- If you don't use Splash, you don't have to worry about passing cookies - this is taken care of by Scrapy. Just make sure you don't put COOKIES_ENABLED=False in your settings.py

Comment: wow! very very appreciate your help @Wim! now i can also get the price of the items!:) Have you ever considered about giving some teaching lessons?

One more question: where does the "req" in front of  FormRequest come from?

Comment: If I find people that want to pay me for teaching lessons I'll definitely consider that - until then I will just answer questions on StackOverflow :). The req is just a variable name used to assign the request to (useful when trying out in scrapy shell) - no need to use it in your script I think

Comment: Is there a way, i can contact you privately? Alright thanks for that! With your help, i finished all of my crawler projects today!♥

Comment: @y.y you can find a link to my GitHub (and email there) on my profile